# Luggage storage in Tulum, Mexico?

Tags: mexico, luggage-storage

Is there a luggage storage at the bus terminal in Tulum, Mexico? I read somewhere that it got closed a few years ago and now I'm searching for a way to deposit my luggage. We'll be having two big backpacks.

Comment: Two articles, one on [TripAdvisor](https://www.tripadvisor.com/ShowTopic-g499447-i10052-k9407173-Valladolid_to_Tulum_via_Coba_Luggage_Storage-Coba_Yucatan_Peninsula.html) and the another in [The San Diego Reader](http://www.sandiegoreader.com/news/2015/mar/13/spring-break-detour-tuluum-coba/#) suggest that you can store them for a small fee at the restaurant in front of the bus stop

Comment: This is for the maya site Coba, which is in fact not Tulum, as far as I know?

Comment: It seems to be only place en route to Tulum in which to store luggage.

Answer (score 2):

> Luggage storage in Tulum, Mexico?

It may have helped to specify whether Tulum Pueblo, Tulum Playa or Tulum Ruinas but there were (and hopefully still are!) lockers to rent at for example [El Grand Cenote](http://wikitravel.org/en/Tulum) and [Many beach clubs rent gear and also provide lockers, bathrooms, and change rooms.](https://travelyucatan.com/tulum-mexico/)

There does not appear to be a facility at the bus station any longer.

Answer (score 0):

Hello the office All About Tulum have Luggage storage across the street from the ADO Busstation. Any sice is 20mxn each Hour. We are open from 8am - 10pm. We have as well Lockers 
and Printing services.